# QT creator get the time from another time zone (not local time zone)

Tags: c++, time, qt5

I was trying to find how to get a current time, however, I am looking to get a time from another time zone. I tried to play with it, even trying to simply add hours to the current time, to make up to what I am trying to get, but it did not work well

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(showTime()));
    timer->start();

    QDate date = QDate::currentDate();
    QString dateTimeText = date.toString();
    ui->date->setText(dateTimeText);


}

void MainWindow::showTime()
{
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString time_text = time .toString("hh : mm : ss");
    if((time.second() % 2) == 0)
    {
        time_text[3] = ' ';
        time_text[8] = ' ';
    }
    ui->Digital_clock->setText(time_text);

}
```

Comment: Qt has dedicated functions for time zones, `QDateTime::toTimeZone(const QTimeZone &timeZone)`, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `QTime` for different time zone, you could just create new `QTime` object based on `currentTime()` with specific offset.

To do that you can just call `addSecs(int)` function like below:

```cpp
QTime currentTimeZoneTime = QTime::currentTime(); // Your time zone current time
QTime differentTimeZoneTime = localTime.addSecs(3600); // Add +1 hour to your time zone current time
```